# C++ term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments thread sockets

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock

Recently, I've been trying to make a socket server that accepts multiple clients. I am using basic threads (and I don't want to use the boost library). But I get the error `'term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments thread sockets'` everytime, and it is because of the threading. If I comment the threading, it does work.

Anybody who can help me with that?

Here is the code:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

class TcpClient {
private:
    SOCKET s;
    SOCKADDR_IN a;
    std::thread t;
public:
    TcpClient(SOCKADDR_IN addr, SOCKET client) {
        this->s = client;
        this->a = addr;

        this->t = std::thread(&TcpClient::receiving_func);
        this->t.join();
    }

    void receiving_func(void* v) {
        for (;;) {
            char* data = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytes = recv(this->s, data, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
            std::string raw = std::string(data);
            raw = raw.substr(0, bytes);
            printf_s("Received %s\n", raw);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::thread` needs to be able to call the function you give it. It can't guess arguments.

Comment: `TcpClient::receiving_func` needs to be static

Comment: What do you mean? I was looking at a code example on a website and I just edited it to work with my example. How should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`receiving_func(void* v)` takes 1 argument, but `std::thread(&TcpClient::receiving_func);` requires a function that takes zero arguments. What do you believe `v` will be in the function?

You could perhaps `std::thread(&TcpClient::receiving_func, NULL);` to compile (and set `v == NULL`), or since you're not using `v`, just remove it from the method signature.

Additionally, since `receiving_func` is an object method (it's not static), this is a problem, since there's no way to identify the `this` value. You probably want to make the function static, make its parameter a `TcpClient *`, and create the thread with `std::thread(&TcpClient::receiving_func, this);`, and finally, use the parameter to access the object members instead of `this` (as there is no `this` on a static method).

Comment: Even without void* v, it still doesn't work and gives the same error.

Comment: @mah the `receiving_func` function has to be static also